# jupyter notebook X bootstrap

Tags: jupyter-notebook

is it possible to integrate bootstrap components into a Juptyer Notebook. 
 ie: Making markdown tabs specific colors(making the whole markdown cell red), using glyph icons, etc

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah.  At least the alerts, you can just use the html code in a markdown cell.

For example,

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
   <strong>Hi!</strong> This is a blue note.
</div>
```

would give you the blue alerts.  Change info to success, warning, and danger are your options.

Comment: Thanks so much. Maybe you can detail what additional information would help. All bootstrap doesn’t work, just the alerts really.

Comment: I've tried it in vs code without success :(

Comment: Only the classic notebook will render these; try using with anaconda and run the classic notebook.